# ReadTimeOutException in Netty is not closing the channel when writing a response to the client

Tags: netty

I have a Netty server. The first handler is a `ReadTimeoutHandler` followed by the business logic handler and a response writer handler. Say the time out is set to 20 sec. Whenever there is a time out i want to do three things in the response writer handler `exceptionCaught()`:

1. Write a response back to client
2. Close on some other threads that my business logic started
3. Close the channel

The most important issue is that the read time out should be conveyed to the client at the correct time.

**Question 1**

If I do only **3**, the client sees the timeout correctly after 20 sec. However if I do both **1** and **3**, i.e. try to write a response before closing on the channel, the timeout message is printed after the business logic thread is finished, which might take 40 sec. Where I am going wrong here?

```
channel.write(....).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)
```

vs.

```
channel.close()
```

**Question 2**

How can I force the termination of the business logic thread if there is a timeout, considering I am not catching the exception in the business logic handler but in a handler after that.

Comment: The first one might be a bug in Netty or your application.  Would you mind if I ask you to write a small application/test case that demonstrates the problem?

The second one is not really a Netty question but about dealing with interrupts / signals between multiple threads.  Well written business logic should terminate itself when `Thread.interrupt()` is called on the business logic thread.